# How do you add google sheet cell data into an html-email using Google Scripts for Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, html-email

I'm working on a script add-on for Sheets to send an invoice. I'd like to take data from a cell and add it directly into an html chart and then email this to clients. I'm having difficulty getting the data from the cell into the html chart.

I've built [with the help of this community] a script that can send an html chart from Sheets into an email. However, the cell values never come out properly in the email [after I add them into the HTML format].

```js
function composeChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]
  var data = sheet.getRange(4,2);
  var date = data.getValues();
  //var chartComplete = titleChart+date+TD+date+TD+TR+endChart;
  
  var html2 =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> Test </h2><br />' +
        '<p> Greetings Earthling </p>' +
        '<TABLE>'+ 
   '<TR>'+
      data +'</TD>'+
      '<TD>' + data + '</TD>'+
   '</TR>'+
   '<TR>'+
      '<TD>Data 3</TD>'+
      '<TD>Data 4</TD>'+
   '</TR>'+
   '<TR>'+
      '<TD>Data 5</TD>'+
      '<TD>Data 6</TD>'+
   '</TR>'+
'</TABLE>'+
    '</body>' 
  
  testMailApp3(html2, data);
}

function testMailApp3(html2, data) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    'bakukai@gmail.com',         // recipient
    'test MailApp DATA',                  // subject 
    'TEST'+data, {                        // body
      htmlBody: html2                 // advanced options
    }
  ); 
}
```

I'd like the chart to look like this [ideally with simple borders, not shown below]:

```
DATE    4/5 4/12 4/19 4/26
AMOUNT  231 213  424  213
```

Comment: Your `data` variable is a range and does not hold any values yet. Take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), which shows that you need to acquire the values of the range before you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

### Some remarks

- Arrays start with the index 0, rather than 1. So if you want to get the first sheet of your spreadsheet -it should be  `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]`.
- Data in your case is just the dat containing range, not its contents. The contents are assigned to the variable `date` - in a 2-dimensional array.
- Is all your data located in one cell? 
  The code implementation would be easier if every element you want to insert in  were located in a separate cell.
- From your range definition `getRange(4,2)` I undestand that all your data is contained in the single cell `B4`. In this case you need to convert the content of the 2-dimensional array `date` to a string and [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) your string into substrings, e.g. `var stringArray=date[0][0].toString().split(" ");` - provided the entries are separated by spaces
- The above step will assign your values to array elements of the 1-dimensional array `stringArray`
- in the next step you can embed the array elements within the HTML code:

```html
'<TR>'+ stringArray[0] +'</TD>'+ '<TD>' + stringArray[1] + '</TD>'...
```